# In Mono on OSX how do I get access to the current proxy?

Tags: .net, macos, proxy, mono, monomac

Both [GetSystemWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getsystemwebproxy.aspx) and [DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx) return null.

```
WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

Comment: If there is indeed a proxy in place, this sounds like a potential bug.

Comment: @Noldorin yes there is a proxy in place. although feel free to replicate, it is possible it is an environmental issue.

Comment: Next time I boot up to OS X with Mono, I'll definitely give it a go... Mono isn't as well tested on OS X traditionally, but yeah. Good luck anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a recent version of [monomac](https://github.com/mono/monomac) (or build it from source) then you should be able to call the static method `CFNetwork.GetDefaultProxy` ([source](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/CoreFoundation/CFProxySupport.cs), look at the end of the file) to get an [`IWebProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebproxy.aspx) instance that should match what OSX is using.