# How to use iOS proxy settings with web services 2.0 (System.Net.IWebProxy) in Monotouch?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, xamarin.ios, webproxy

I'm consuming a Webservice 2.0 via SOAP.

My service has a Proxy property of type `System.Net.IWebProxy`.
I would like to use the proxy settings that are configured on the iOS device I'm running on.

Simple question: how? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8055946/220643) for: [In Mono on OSX how do I get access to the current proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8004011/220643)

I have not tried it myself but it should be identical to what MonoMac is using.

Comment: Yet another one. I found WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy()...I'll try yours.